# Unable to get installer types in the assbmely. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: windows-installer

Somebody please help me with this because I'm about to lose my mind.

I created a Windows service in C#/Visual Studio 2015/.Net 4.6.1. Then I created a simple installer for it, using the built-in template. Custom actions, ProjectInstaller class - everything works.

I ran this installer on several computers and everything worked well, until I tried to install it on a specific client's Windows Server 2012, and suddenly I get

```
Unable to get installer types in the [xxx].exe assbmely. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

So far, what I've tried is:

1. Installed .Net 4.6.1 on the server (wasn't installed before).
2. Switch all of the service's dependencies to CopyLocal=false, and then back again.
3. Ran Fusion Log and got no binding errors whatsoever.
4. Ran the MSI with full logging and got a completely useless log that simply shows the same error again.
5. Placed try/catch around all code paths in the ProjectInstaller class. No help.

This is driving me CRAZY. How can I know exactly which dll/type if giving me the problem if there's no way to log what's going on?!

Can anyone please HELP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your custom action assembly, the service. The types it wants are from your installer assembly, which is loaded and instantiated using reflection to discover the installer classes. Fusion logs show no errors for the same reason, creation and instantiation via reflection. Internally there is no Windows Installer support for managed code installer classes, so there is a C++ shim Dll that does all this on your behalf, and there are no diagnostics from this black box Dll.

Some suggestions:

1. You didn't post the architecture (64/32) of your setup (TargetPlatform), and if your assembly is AnyCpu, 64, 32 bit etc. Some Windows Servers do not install the 32-bit subsystem by default -WoW64 is optional - so there may be no support at all for anything 32-bit. If this is the case you need to build a 64-bit install and make your assemblies 64-bit.
2. You may have a dependency on another assembly that is not available. This seems unlikely, but keep it in mind.
3. I believe this issue is fixed, but this gives you an idea of what happens with managed code custom actions and why they have previously failed on 64-bit systems. Again, this comes down to your setup's TargetPlatform and whether your install is x86 or x64, and whether the Server 2016 has any support for WoW64 installed.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio/

Anyway these might point you towards a solution. By the way, "real installers", if I can use that term, don't use managed code to install services because Windows Installer has built-in support to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. My project was x86; I just rebuilt it to target x64 (had to go through Orca of course), and now it works. So let me get this straight... some Windows Servers simply don't install the 32bit sub-system - so my 32bit application can't run this 32 bit shim dll because it can't find it?

Comment: I got a solution at https://www.intowindows.com/3-ways-to-uninstall-programs-that-wont-uninstall-in-windows-10/
Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the `Unable to get installer types in the [xxx].exe` business with my .NET 4.8 project. This is a windows forms application formulated in the newer SDK style (I actually used the dotnet 5 windows project template and just changed the TFM)

With ye olde Windows Installer, I had to do a couple of things:

1. Right Click the installer project > select `View` > select `Launch Conditions` and ensure that the required framework matched my winform project
2. In the past I only had to put the `primary output`, but now it seems I need to add the `Publish Items` output, too

[image]

Those were the things that put me over the finish line.

Prior to that I did some fiddling with platform targets like AnyCPU vs x64 etc..
For whatever it's worth, here's the winform build configuration:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <DocumentationFile>Ross.Windows.Forms.RFPWorkQueue.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And my TargetPlatform of the installer is currently x86